# EMR is writing all logs in /mnt and causing no space in device for a large 60 gb dataset processing

Tags: amazon-emr

EMR is writing all logs in `/mnt` and causing no space in device for a large 60 gb dataset processing. I tried multiple option by changing the configuration in EMR cluster as below but still EMR is only writing to `/mnt` and encountering space issue. Am I missing some configuration?  Is there any alternative?

```
[
  {
    "Classification": "yarn-site",
    "Properties": {
      "yarn.nodemanager.localizer.cache.cleanup.interval-ms": "400000",
      "yarn.nodemanager.localizer.cache.target-size-mb": "5120"
    }
  },
  {
    "Classification": "mapred-site",
    "Properties": {
      "mapred.local.dir": "/mnt/mapred,/mnt1/mapred,/mnt2/mapred"
    }
  },
  {
    "Classification": "spark",
    "Properties": {
      "spark.local.dir": "/mnt/mapred,/mnt1/mapred,/mnt2/mapred"
    }
  }
]
```